# cannot access files inside folder in next js

Tags: next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

i am working dynamic routing in next j s,and folder structure is like

```
pages:
_app.j s
index.j s

main_Page:
  cart:
    [...cart_Component.j s]
  about:
    [...about_Component.j s]
  [[...index]].j s
```

and here my [[...index]].j s file is dynamic and i need to show all countries data until any country selected from header drop down and after need to show the data based on selected country in [[...index]].j s,so have taken it as dynamic from index.j s =>[[...index]].j s

but my problem is when i want to go to cart from home,i am writing like this

```
Router.push(`/main_Page/${this.state.country_Name}/cart/${cart_Name}`)
```

it is not navigating to cart page stayed in [[...index]].j s,so i have renamed cart as [cart]
then i was able to go to cart,but my problem is when i want navigate to about page i have renamed it also like [about] it throws an error like

```
error: you cannot use different slug names for the same dynamic path
```

when i am routing to any page it's going to [cart] page,please help

Comment: The folder structure you have would expect a URL like `/main_Page/cart/${cart_Name}` to match the `cart` route. If you want the country name in there you need to account for it in the folder structure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i have changed my folder structure to

```
pages:
_app.j s
index.j s

[main_Page]:
  cart:
    [...cart_Component.j s]
  about:
    [...about_Component.j s]
  [[...index]].j s
```

with country:

```
Router.push(`/${this.state.country_Name}/cart/${cart_Name}`)
```

without country:

```
Router.push(`/main_Page/cart/${cart_Name}`)
```